# If page not found then go to default page instead of displaying 404

Tags: python, django

I have a model that contains user names as well as user ids.
I have created a view that will display that information to me if I try to access a link of the type

```
serverAddress/users/<user_id>/
```

I did this by creating a simple view that looks like this.

```
def detail(request, user_uuid):
    user = get_object_or_404(RegUser, user_uuid=user_uuid)
    return render(request, 'accessManager/detail.html', {'user': user})
```

In case a user id that does not exist on my database is found, instead of displaying a *404 page not found error* I want to display a form so that a new user with that non-existing id can be registered.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you can't use `get_object_or_404` method. But you can use a `try...except` statement to catch `RegUser.DoesNotExist` exception.

EDIT: Fixed code.

```
def detail(request, user_uuid):
    try:
        user = RegUser.objects.get(user_uuid=user_uuid)
        # do something
    except RegUser.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/of/register/page/')

    return render(request, 'accessManager/detail.html', {'user': user})
```

Comment: I am trying to make this work but no matter the uuid I enter it will simply use my *detail.html* template to display it, even if that *uuid* does not exist. Is it possible that you made a small mistake somewhere?

Comment: It seems that partly Luftars' answer is correct because you have to use `RegUser.objects.get` not simply RegUser.

Comment: @green_leaf Oh, sorry! Didn't know I missed it. I feel terrible.

Comment: Well its corrected now, so anyone else interested in this will see the right solution. Thanks for the quick edit.

Answer (score 1):

Following previous answer: It should be

```
def detail(request, user_uuid):

    try:
        user = RegUser.objects.get(user_uuid=user_uuid)
    except:
        user = None

    if user:
        return render(request, 'accessManager/detail.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accessManager/new_user.html')
```

Comment: It't not a good practice to use `except` statement without the exception you wish to catch.

Comment: I agree. Your answer is better.

Comment: Also, rendering a template without any context may lead to incomplete displays...'new_user.html' may require some variables on it's template...prefer a redirect over a direct render.